# Show Windows and Linux Server firewall data to a azure solution

Tags: windows, azure, redhat, firewall

This is Yaseen Zafar. DevOps Engineer from Integrated Dealer Systems. We have multiple customers whose servers are hosted on multiple locations from Canada to America. They are hosted on premises (i.e. they are not currently on Azure). Though we are currently using Microsoft Azure Log Analytics to get some insights of the Windows and Linux Servers. So far it has been a very good experience.

Actually I wanted to know if there is any solution available on Azure that can show me firewall related logs, rules, IP and port details ingested from the Windows and Linux Servers that are hosted on premise location.

Best Regards.

Yaseen Zafar

Answer (score 1):

•   Yes, there is a way through which you can forward your on-premises firewall logs to Azure log analytics workspace since almost every firewall device has syslog functionality in built in it to forward logs to a log management server on a specific port. Thus, similarly, on-premises firewall logs that include all data collected related to the traffic passed inbound and outbound to the environment can be forwarded to a Linux virtual machine which then can be forwarded to the Azure Log Analytics.

•   Syslog is the cross-platform equivalent of Windows Event log which can be leveraged by forwarding these syslog messages to Azure Log Analytics through Linux machines. This linux system should be deployed as a virtual appliance (VM) in on-premises or in Azure cloud such that the syslog-generating firewalls can communicate directly with them. The Linux forwarder can be on-premises physically near the firewall, or it can be in Azure or another cloud, connected to your firewall by an IPSEC tunnel. The Linux computer has a Log Analytics agent configured to communicate with your Log Analytics workspace.

•   Once your firewall is connected to Azure Log Analytics you should create a custom dashboard solution that suits your needs. You will have excellent visibility and gain a lot of insight into your firewall operation by studying the collected and indexed syslog data in the Log search feature of the Azure portal. You will notice which types of data your firewall is delivering and learn what to monitor to meet your business and security needs.

Please find the below links for more information on how to configure the Linux virtual machine as a syslog forwarder and how to implement the above stated solution as a whole: -

https://blog.johnjoyner.net/connect-your-firewall-to-azure-log-analytics-for-security-insights/

https://accountabilit.com/azure-log-analytics-best-syslog-destination/